# MySQL / PHP - Display all data from a table in a while loop without the loop being in the template file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on trying to display all the entries from a table on a page however I want it done so that I have "functions.php" which gets the data and loops it all, but then just have a simple include of some sort (without using include or require etc) in say page.php.

So essentially page.php would act as a template file and the functions file would be where all the code is written and sorted out etc etc if that makes sense?

So far I have this which is pulling the information from the table in as I want it to, however I have no idea how I'd go about while looping it in page.php.

It'd be great if I could just put {DISPLAY_POSTS} in page.php and it'd work but that's just wishful thinking really. It can be done, the phpBB team did it for the forum software but I'm sure it's way more complicated.

My code for getting the data from the table is...

```
$posts = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM " . $dbprefix . "posts") or die($posts . "<br/>" . mysqli_error());

while($postsData = mysqli_fetch_array($posts)) {
    $data1      = $postsData['post1'];
    $data2      = $postsData['post2'];
}
```

THANK YOU!

P.S. As you may have guessed from previous posts, I'm new to StackOverflow and I'm a beginner at PHP so some things may go over my head.

Comment: "but then just have a simple include of some sort (without using include or require etc)" --This confuses me. If you don't include the file how do you expect it to be...included?

Comment: If you're wanting to have placeholders in your templates like {DISPLAY_POSTS} you should create a template engine or use one that already exists, such as [RainTPL](https://github.com/rainphp/raintpl).

Comment: Really too broad of a question here, as in essence you are asking how to build a templating framework. Why not use an existing one?

Comment: Yeah I guess now you mention it that is kinda of what I'm asking.I tried to use `<?php while($postsData) { ?>` and `<?php } ?>` which had the HTML markup inside it with different PHP variables but what I found is that it just doesn't display anything. No errors either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code will result in `$data1` and `$data2` containing only information from the last row of your table because you overwrite the variables in every iteration. To prevent this, you should do something like this:

```
$posts = []; // this is where a new array is created
while($postsData = mysqli_fetch_array($posts)) {
    $posts[] = $postsData; // adds the current record to the array
}
```

which will provide you with a two-dimensional array containing all your posts.

Second, to separate the logic from the presentation, you can use a template engine like [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). The engine takes a [template](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html) and inserts the data from your array to render a complete result. An example for a template `page.twig` would be:

```
<ul>
{% for item in posts %}
    <li>{{ post.data1 }} - {{ post.data2 }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

`page.php` would then only contain the instruction to render the template with the data from `$posts`:

```
echo $twig->render('page.twig', array('posts' => $posts));
```

See the documentation of [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) for further details.

The separation of logic and presentation in general covers many aspects which are addressed by a wide range of frameworks. The most common approach is Model-View-Controller or MVC which will probably point you to more advanced information.

Comment: Hm, I tried that and it didn't work. Something about not being able to use variables as arrays or something. Would I be able to achieve this by wrapping the while loop in a function and just displaying the function in the template page?

Comment: `$posts` is created as an array and should therefore not raise such an error. In principle, you can wrap the while loop in a function but then you should print the relevant fields of `$postData` instead of adding them to `$posts`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to output your all looped data on the template page with a single short code then you have to merge all looped data..

```
$posts = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM " . $dbprefix . "posts") or die($posts . "<br/>" . mysqli_error());

while($postsData = mysqli_fetch_array($posts)) {
    $data1.=$postsData['post1'];
    $data2.=$postsData['post2'];
}

echo $data1;
echo $data2;
```

Now try to add your short code on your template page..